# Bing map supported culture

Tags: silverlight, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am using bing map in silverlight application and having issues in localizing the tile culture. I want to support 3 different bing map tiles culture which are English, Japanese and Chinese (Traditional). For changing culture of tiles following code is used:

```
map.Culture = "zh-Hant"; // For Chinese (Traditional)
map.Culture = "ja"; // For Japanese
map.Culture = "en-US"; // For English (United States)
```

The above code works well when culture selected is English or Japanese but when Chinese is selected tiles renders in English.

Just wanted to know why Chinese tiles are not being rendered?

I have checked the url which bing map is using to get tiles and that is:

Japanese

http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r13200.png?g=1&mkt=ja&shading=hill&n=z

English

http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r13200.png?g=1&mkt=en&shading=hill&n=z

Chinese

http://ecn.t1.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r13200.png?g=1&mkt=zh-Hant&shading=hill&n=z

One can open the above Url's in browser to check the behavior. For 1 and 2 Japanese and English tiles will load but for 3rd URL English tiles will load instead of Chinese.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Maps Silverlight control is an old control and it only supports a small number of cultures. It is also nearing end of life and will stop working next year: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/discon-control-migrat-guide.aspx It is not recommended that you do any new development with this control, or with Silverlight for that matter as the end of life for Silverlight was announced a few years ago.

The Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control is the primary map control used by Bing Maps users. It supports a large number of cultures compared to the Silverlight and other older map controls.